# how to make customized ISO?

Tags: rhel, iso

I have made changes in RHEL starting from partition and also I have changed so many parameters. Now I want to use this changed OS as ISO image so that I can directly install it without doing all the stuff again.

Comment: Probably you'll get several different answers to this question - there are many ways - but in Linux all filesystems are ( more or less ) basically extensions to VFS - the kernel's base filesystem. In this way it makes little difference to the kernel if you're installing from a CD image or any other kind of disk image - it's just a file. The quickest way would be like `cat $DISK | zcat image.file` and restoring is just the reverse action.

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks for replying. i have made five partitions and i want to reflect these changes and also how much the current os is taking as an .iso image.

Comment: Well, without a little ingenuity, you can't partition an ISO regardless. Still, there's nothing stopping you from having 5 or 20 or as many partitions as you want in any regular file. cp /dev/somedev ./somedev.file will read the block device into a file image. mount ./somedev.file /mnt/somemnt will mount it - so long as you've got properly configured loop devices, and you've had those since at least kernel 2.4 probably.

Comment: You probably want to look into [kickstart](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/ch-kickstart2.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can install `remastersys` and change your OS, finally create an ISO with `remastersys`.

Comment: It works on both Ubuntu and Debian distros and any of their derivatives, and doesn't work on RHEL

Comment: I thought it broke like 4 years ago...

Comment: you can see: http://bashinglinux.wordpress.com/tag/rhel/

Comment: you can see: http://scientificlinuxforum.org/index.php?showtopic=72

Comment: you can see: http://solidsmoke.blogspot.ch/2008/12/remastering-red-hat-enterprise-linux-5.html

Comment: you can visit: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_a_Live_CD

Comment: You can visit: https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/60959

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh Thanks for giving reply. if i follow the steps and making a new minimal rhel6.3 with the partitions how i created while installing rhel6.3 will it effect everything in the new image.